# How to connect VPN external protected by password to GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, mikrotik

I already followed a [video tutorial about connect VPN external from AWS to GCP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhrU3-6afuc). Actually my VPN external not from AWS but mikrotik (using email and password for login) different with that's video tutorial. So its made me confuse because always got "Not Incoming Packets" status. How I can fix it?

Note: I am still newbie about GCP

Cheers

Comment: I found this third party [tutorial](https://ivo.schooneman.net/2017/06/vpn-google-cloud-mikrotik-router/) that may help in your use-case (English below on the page). Furthermore, you may check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/advanced#mtu) for advanced config. Most common issues are caused by MTU size which should be less than 1460 on the router per this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/mtu-considerations)

Comment: thanks @Fady. Its already fixed with my friend after setup new tunnel from mikrotik side

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am glad it is fixed. Is it possible to provide an answer about the fix for the benefit of the community ?